# Packing a specific number of equally sized rectangles on a grid with obstacles most effectively

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to find an algorithm that can place a specific number of equally sized rectangles in a grid with obstacles. The rectangles should not overlap and the total distance to a given starting position should be minimal.

[image] [image]

The red are the obstacles and the orange are the rectangles being placed (in this case 9). The green point is the anchor point, the total distance of all orange rectangles to this point should be minimal.

Comment: Is there a reason the spots diagonally up-left and diagonally down-left aren’t chosen in your example?

Comment: No, there is not. Those indeed may be closer depending on where on the rectangles you measure it.

Comment: Are the rectangles necessarily aligned to the grid and 1x1?

Comment: Do you appricate the answer, if so, please accept.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the problem a bit around: We have a grid of squares and need to overlay and position this with your obstacles. If we move the obstacles one square on the grid horizontal or vertical, we have all possible options covered (else we would repeat the same situation).

Assume the gird is a 10mm grid. When we start moving -left, we only have to  test for positions of the obstacle boundaries. (0, -5, -6, -7)

[image]

At Position 0, we have 16 whole squares (image above)

At Position -5, we have 11 whole squares (image below)

[image]

At position -6, we have 11 whole squares and at position -7 we have 14 whole square.

[image]
[image]

### **We can conclude that position 0 is the best position for our horizontal alignment.**

We can repeat this process above for the vertical alignment. We conclude **(0, -5)** is our best optimized position with 19 squares.

[image]